# How to find Constructor Arguments for verification on Etherscan.io

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, constructor, contract-verification

I spent 4 days for this work.

plz make me know anybody.

this is solidity code of my token
I use openzeppelin.

---

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.9.2/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";

contract Happycat is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, ERC20Permit {
    constructor() ERC20("Happycat", "Hcat") ERC20Permit("Hcat") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000000000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

---

token contract is

0xB8e0ddC1db55EAFf61D65BDC483Ff8e2aB26869A

kind anybody..
make me know abi encoded constructor arguments of my token plz

Comment: additional question. Which mod should I use on Etherscan?
single file? multi file? json?

Comment: The constructor doesn't accept parameters so it should be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would suggest using hardhat and ethers for developing smart contracts, everything becomes easy with these tools.

If you want to directly paste your code and verify then you can use this website to encode your arguments and then paste it https://abi.hashex.org/